# std::uniform_real_distribution and rand()

Tags: c++, random

Why is `std::uniform_real_distribution` better than `rand()` as the random number generator? Can someone give an example please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The real comparison is between `rand` and one of the random number engines provided by the C++11 standard library. `std::uniform_real_distribution` just distributes the output of an engine according to some parameters (for example, real values between 10 and 20). You could just as well make an engine that uses `rand` behind the scenes.

Now the difference between the standard library random number engines and using plain old `rand` is in guarantee and flexibility. `rand` provides no guarantee for the quality of the random numbers - in fact, many implementations have shortcomings in their distribution and period. If you want some high quality random numbers, `rand` just won't do. However, the quality of the random number engines is defined by their algorithms. When you use `std::mt19937`, you know exactly what you're getting from this thoroughly tested and analysed algorithm. Different engines have different qualities that you may prefer (space efficiency, time efficiency, etc.) and are all configurable.

This is not to say you should use `rand` when you don't care too much. You might as well just start using the random number generation facilities from C++11 right away. There's no downside.

Comment: In addition, generators are required to generate the same sequence (given the same seed) on all platforms, which is important for reproducibility.

Answer (score 12):

First, it should be made clear that the proposed comparison is nonsensical.

`uniform_real_distribution` is not a random number generator. You cannot produce random numbers from a `uniform_real_distribution` without having a random number generator that you pass to its [`operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution/operator%28%29). `uniform_real_distribution` "shapes" the output of that random number generator into an uniform real distribution. You can plug various kinds of random number generators into a distribution.

I don't think this makes for a decent comparison, so I will be comparing the use of `uniform_real_distribution` with a C++11 random number generator against `rand()` instead.

Another obvious difference that makes the comparison even less useful is the fact that `uniform_real_distribution` is used to produce floating point numbers, while `rand()` produces integers.

That said, there are several reasons to prefer the new facilities.

`rand()` is global state, while when using the facilities from `<random>` there is no global state involved: you can have as many generators and distributions as you want and they are all independent from each other.

`rand()` has no specification about the quality of the sequence generated. The random number generators from C++11 are all well-specified, and so are the distributions. `rand()` implementations can be, and in practice have been, of very poor quality, and not very uniform.

`rand()` provides a random number within a predefined range. It is up to the programmer to adjust that range to the desired range. *This is not a simple task*. No, it is not enough to use % something. Doing this kind of adjustment in such a naive manner will most likely destroy whatever uniformity was there in the original sequence. `uniform_real_distribution` does this range adjustment for you, correctly.

Comment: Why are you saying that `uniform_real_distribution` is not a random number generator? What is then a RNG for you?

Comment: Great info, but could you clarify that 2nd para pls - It's confusing - specifically because http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution seems to imply that it is a random number generator (I suspect there is a subtle difference that I don't see)

Comment: @akappa something like std::mt19937, or std::knuth_b, for example. `uniform_real_distribution`, as the name indicates, is just a random number distribution. See what the argument for its `operator()` is: a generator!

Comment: @Caribou sure, I will try to clarify that. The docs are just a bit lax on the terminology.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes thanks - that'll teach me not to actually read the class description properly - cheers

Comment: @akappa FWIW I am using the terminology from the C++ standard.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: your recent edit of your answer made your point clear. Thank you for your efforts to clarify it.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is actually in the name of the function, which is the fact that the uniformity of the distribution of random numbers is better with `std::uniform_real_distribution` compared to the uniform distribution of random numbers that `rand()` provides.

The distribution for `std::uniform_real_distribution` is of course between a given interval [a,b).

Essentially, that is saying that the probability *density* that when you ask for a random number between 1 and 10 is as great of getting 5 or getting 9 or any other of the possible values with `std::uniform_real_distribution`, as when you'd do it with `rand()` and call it several times, the probability of getting 5 instead of 9 may be different.

Comment: but if I write a function to generate a random number, is is a good approximation then or is it still better to use std::uniform_real_distribution?

Comment: The probability of all possible values is equal? I highly doubt it, that wouldn't be a uniform distribution since the density of floating-point values itself is different at different scales. What should be uniform is the probability _density_.